# Chosen multiple select becomes huge when many/all options are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

When using Chosen.js on a multiple select field, if there are over 500 options that the user has selected, the list just becomes ridiculously long.

[image]

Is there any way I could limit the number of show elements? For example when chosing over 3 options, the user will have **(4) options are selected...**, instead of them being listed.

[image]

I wonder why there's no such option in their documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$('.element').chosen().change(function() {
    var totalSelected = $(this).find('option:selected').size();
    var placeholder = $(this).find('option:first-child').text();
    if(totalSelected > 3) {
        $(this).next().find('.chosen-choices').find('li.search-choice').hide(),
        $(this).next().find('.chosen-choices').find('.literal-multiple').show();
        $(this).next().find('.chosen-choices').find('span.literal-multiple').text(placeholder + " ("+totalSelected+")");
    }
});
```

The class `literal-multiple` is a custom element to show the `totalSelected` elements. You need to add it in the prototype of the chosen plugin:

### file chosen.jquery.js

```
Chosen.prototype.set_up_html = function() {
   //stuff
   if(this.is_multiple) {
     var selVal  = this.default_text;
     this.container.html('<ul class="chosen-choices"><span class="literal-multiple"></span></ul>');
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't really work, after I've hit 3 selections, the options are hidden but there's no ".literal-multiple" that shows up.

Comment: You need to try to put a custom element (like this `.literal-multiple`) to put how many elements are selected. Are you trying with prototype?

Comment: Still I wouldn't recommend this solution, because using delete key on keyboard you would remove items from your selection, without triggering 'change' event, the user would still think their selection is complete while some items have been silently deselected.

Comment: Why don't trigger `change` event? If you deselect any items, change event must trigger, doing with keyboard or doing with mouse, it's indifferent.

Comment: Also, when I programatically select all items (which I do), they all get selected and shown the old style. I'd have to trigger change event, chosen:updated event etc. I'd rather wait for something robust.

Comment: With a plugin option is impossible. Chosen doesn't support this way of showing selected elements. You need to programming something in the onChange event, like my example. I use this trick in 3 projects, it runs everything ok. You expect something more robust? Me too....

Comment: Please, notice to me if you found something different that works. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

SOrry I am unable to comment since I don't have enough reputation.
But to add to the previous answer, instead of adding a separate container, 
why don't we just append the n users selected as a <li> item.

Something like this -

```
$('.element').chosen().change(function() {
    var totalSelected = $(this).find('option:selected').size();
    var placeholder = $(this).find('option:first-child').text();
    if(totalSelected > 3) {
       $(this).next().find('.chosen-choices').find('li.search-choice').hide(),
       $(this).next().find('.chosen-choices')append('<li class="search-choice" <span>'+totalSelected+' users selected. </li>');
}
});
```

This seems to work for me.